# Express the product of a binomial distribution for i = 1 to n as a sum

Tags: self-learning, products, maximum-likelihood

I am told that
$$f(y|p) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1-p)^yp $$
$$=p^n(1-p)^{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}$$
What are the steps to get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

$$\begin{split}f(y|p)&=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p)^{y_i}p\\
&=\underbrace{p*p*...*p}_{\text {n}}*(1-p)^{y_1}*(1-p)^{y_2}*...*(1-p)^{y_n}\\
&=p^n(1-p)^{y_1+y_2+...+y_n}\\
&=p^n(1-p)^{\sum_{i=1}^ny_i}\end{split}$$